# WebGLError uniformMatrix4fv

Tags: webgl, uniform

I am developing a webgl app. uniformMatrix4fv works on new versions of Chrome, but I'm getting an error for old versions. The error is:

> Failed to execute 'uniformMatrix4fv' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

How can I fix this?

Comment: "What should I do?" You should show your code by making a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349790/128511) and putting it in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: "How can I fix this?" Stop trying to call the function wrong. Since you haven't provided a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349790/128511) we can't tell you how to fix it.