# Failed to execute 'uniformMatrix4fv'

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm very new to OpenGL and Javascript so I'm not sure what exactly is wrong. I am making a program that rotates a shape along all three axes x,y and z. I am trying to multiply my position vectors with a rotation matrix but I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'uniformMatrix4fv' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`

Here is my vertex shader, I've shortened it to hide the unnecessary code which already works so I can highlight where I am having the problem. I have the multiplication here also:

```
attribute vec2 pos;
uniform mat4 rotation;

void main(){

 gl_Position = rotation*vec4(vec3(pos,0),1);

 gl_Position.x = pos.x*cos(shift) - pos.y*sin(shift);
 gl_Position.y = pos.y*cos(shift)  + pos.x*sin(shift);
 gl_Position.z =0.0;
 gl_Position.w =1.0;
}
```

This is one of the rotation functions, I am doing one for each axis. The rotation matrix which is 4x4 looks like this:

```
function xAxis(angle){
var c = Math.cos(angle);
var s = Math.sin(angle);

return[
1,0,0,0,
0,c,-s,0,
0,s,c,0,
0,0,0,1
];
}
```

But when I try to use this command inside the draw function I get an error

```
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rotationLocation, false, rotation);
```

So my question is how do I fix this error?

EDIT: I should add that I am using a Javascript file as well as an HTML file. All the important code, so the vertex shader, fragment shader etc, is inside the Javascript file.

EDIT 2: I should also add that the program worked fine before I added these lines of code.

EDIT 3: Here's a [Link to my Javascript code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XVtTjj-Gk3GzwdOfT1uSIX8AYtDJPsnY/view?usp=sharing) I converted it to a text file for easier reading

Comment: Try reducing to a minimum viable example as as asked in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55065981/webglerror-uniformmatrix4fv

Comment: @wcochran thanks I'll try that now

Comment: Jason, You need to add more code. @Spektre, your comment is not relevant for WebGL.

Comment: @gman I think I will just link the entire javascript file because I'm not sure exactly how much code I need to add. I had more code but I was told to remove from it

Comment: Try to print out the `rotationLocation`

Comment: It might be a problem that you use `false` instead of `gl.FALSE` maybe some browser version have problems with that

Comment: Linking to your code doesn't make your question on to topic for stack overflow. You have to put enough code **in the question itself** for the question to be answerable. As it is it's not answerable with only what's in the question itself. There are plenty of questions with lots more code. See other WebGL questions for examples

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I solved it

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured out the problem. I accidentally created 2 `xAxis()` functions in my program. The way I designed it, the first one would identify which axis to rotate around, and the second one would do the matrix multiplication. I mistakenly gave them the same name which gave me the error, when I renamed one to `xAxis_rotate()` my problem got solved.